# Are the following PDEs equivalent?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, parabolic-pde

I would like to consider two PDE

$$\frac{\partial V}{\partial u}=\frac{\partial^{2} V}{\partial x^{2}}$$

such that

$$V(u,0)=\delta(u),V(0,x)=0,Domain=\{u>0,x>0\}$$

and

$$\frac{\partial V}{\partial u}=\frac{\partial^{2} V}{\partial x^{2}}$$

such that

$$V(0,x)=\delta(x),V(u,0)=0,Domain=\{u>0,x>0\}$$ equivalent? It seems that both means that $V(u,x)=0$ when $u>0,x>0$ and has the same physical meaning.

Comment: What is the $u$ variable?

Comment: As an aside, I cannot see the meaning of defining $V(u,0)=\delta(u)$ when you already have a Dirchlet boundary condition. Same follows for the other problem

Comment: The $u$ variable is the time variable. You can treat it as $t$. The reason why I write it down since I want to consider the following situation: suppose I have a rod of semi-infinite length. If I give an initial impulse at one end, after providing a unit impulse, the one end is insulated. I would like to know what would be the temperature of the rod at the point $x>0$ when it is at $u>0$. I am not sure if anyone think of such extreme case yet, and I would like to know how to treat it.

Answer (score 1):

The two pde's are not equivalent. Physically speaking the first one $$\left\{\begin{matrix}\partial_t V = \partial_{xx}^2 V\\ V(0,t) = 0\\ V(x,0)=\delta(x)\end{matrix}\right.$$ means that you want to study some semi-infinite rod that has, as you said,an *insulated* end, to which you give at the start a unit impulse. The second one $$\left\{\begin{matrix}\partial_t V = \partial_{xx}^2 V\\ V(0,t) = \delta(t)\\ V(x,0)=0\end{matrix}\right.$$ means that you have the same semi-infinite rod to which, at any moment, you give a unit impulse at one and that at the start, all the rod is insulated but it is so **just** at the start along **all** the length of the rod!

The first problem seems more resonable to me and can be easily solved by taking the odd extension of the initial conditions and solve the heat equation for all $\mathbb{R}$. But from what I recall the odd extension of the Dirac delta is zero everywhere.
You can see it even using the Green's function to evaluate the solution: the Green's function for this problem is $$G(x,x',t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}}\left(e^{\frac{(x-x')^2}{4t}}-e^{\frac{(x+x')^2}{4t}}\right)$$ for which $$u(x,t) = \int_0^\infty G(x,x',t)\delta(x')dx' = 0 $$
Conceptually speaking, giving a unite impulse on an end which has to be zero all the time won't give anything to the rest of the rod. It's like having an immovable, indestructible wall and you hit it with a running car: the wall won't feel nothing at all. But, on the other hand, for your problem, you could give a unit impulse very close to $x=0$ using an initial condition such as $u(x,0)=\delta(x-\epsilon)$ for a small $\epsilon$